# Why is Safari Content Blocker preventing this redirect when clicked on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, safari-content-blocker

I have created a button/link on my website using Javascript (provided by theBookingButton by Siteminder), this button contains a script that links to another web address when the button is clicked. Safari blocks this from working when their built-in browser "content-blocker" is enabled.

Hoping someone can help with this, I'm lost.

I have tried to create a normal link, but I cannot chose specific criteria, such as check in date.

```
<!--channel code for siteminder booking button-->
<body data-region=”emea” data-channelcode=”propertynamedirect”>

<h1>Redacted text</h1>
<!--First accordion-->
<button class="accordion">Advance Purchase - 15% off</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Enjoy 15% off ... </p>
  </br>
<!--Redeem Button from Siteminder BookingButton-->  
  <div class=center>
<a class="ibe" href="#" data-region="emea" data-channelcode="propertynamedirect" data-query-check_in_date="01-12-2019" data-query-number_nights="2" data-query-campaign="0001">BOOK NOW</a>
</div>


<script src="https://widget.siteminder.com/ibe.min.js"></script>
```

In other browsers (even one's with ublock origin in) the link directs to the new web page, in Safari it does not.